# Xcode 9: Weird side-padding added to table view cell when running on Xcode 9

Tags: ios, uitableview, interface-builder, xcode9

We have a project that was developed on Xcode 8 and recently when we migrated the project to Xcode 9 it's started adding padding to both sides of the Content View although no padding actually given or ever added in Xcode 8.

Note: When the project compiled on Xcode 8 and installed on devices that run both iOS 11 and 12 we don't see this padding.

Also, so you get the full picture, we have a custom cell view in the table cells.

I'm adding some screen shots of the bug/weird behaviour :

[image]

[image]

I've tried to uncheck this option on the interface builder:

[image]

but it didn't changed anything..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show table view constraints.

Comment: @SagarChauhan It's happening in all table views across all the app (about 40-50 table views).